# cannot read property of bind this is not defined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's optional to use bind in constructor if you have bind(this) in jsx correct?

```
render(){
   return(
      <input onChange={this.myFunc.bind(this)} type="text"/>
   )
}

myFunc(){
    alert('should trigger');
}
```

But I got error of cannot read property of bind this error. Here's my full js file http://pastebin.com/yL7BtN8h

Comment: Do `this.myFunc.bind(this)`

Comment: Your Pastebin link doesn't work. Please post *all* relevant code here, not on another site.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input onChange={this.myFunc.bind(this)} type="text"/>
```

And not :

```
  <input onChange={myFunc.bind(this)} type="text"/>
```

Comment: I did that in my file, http://pastebin.com/yL7BtN8h but still got error.

Answer (score 0):

Abdennour is technically correct, but binding the same method each time you call .render() is less efficient than binding once in the constructor.  Many developers consider this methodology a best practice:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
    }

    myFunc(){
        alert('should trigger');
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <input onChange={this.myFunc} type="text"/>
        );
    }
}
```